# The most correct way to put html in array objects in Angular 2?

Tags: arrays, angular

I'm not sure if that's even possible, but I'd like to put HTML inside array objects like for example

```
{'title': 'How to make omelette du fromage', 
'desc': '<div class="container"><div class="row"><p class="big">Just put cheese in your omelette.</p></div></div>'}
```

or I have some pipe that uses `'`like for example

```
{'title': 'Search item', 'code': '<div *ngFor="let item of items | search:'item':query">{{item}}</div>'}
```

... but I'm aware that's dangerous, since HTML uses " and ' which will completely break the structure.

Is there a clean way to do that?

Comment: What is the problem? What part do you think is not clean?

Comment: The part where HTML may sometimes use `"` and `'`. Shouldn't I care about that?

Comment: I still don't get what the problem is. You mean when the HTML string itself contains `'` or `"`? Your example doesn't contain any, therefore I'm not sure what you mean. Just prefix quotes inside the string with `\` if this is possible.

Comment: My code does have `"` inside apostrophes, though. I'm just asking if there's a way where I can write code inside arrays that won't mess with the notation. My example might not be the best one, I agree.

Comment: Please try to improve the example to make it more clear. I still don't get what the problem is. If the outer-most quotes are `'` you can use `"` inside the string just fine (as you have it in your example).

Comment: I have edited. In the second example, the item for 'code' would end in `search:` because that's where the first apostrophe starts. Let me know if it's still confusing.

Comment: Change it to `search:\'item\':query"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use quotes inside other quotes of the same kine, just escape them with `\` like

```
search:\'item\':query"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since HTML in array considered as string you can use \' instead if ' and use \" instead of " . This is applicable for inside content of a string only.